# How can I get the exact reason behind the error message in MS Flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, flow

I am big fan of MS Flow and exploring it day by day.

I have converted many existing business logic to Flow and all are running successfully.

But some how when I am trying to use "Update Item" action of SharePoint it is giving me error.

And the error message is like I am not getting what is causing an error.

My question is, can I get the exact reason behind the error?

Following is the error message that I am getting.

> { "status": 400, "message": "Exception occurred. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))\r\nclientRequestId:
>   3302bfc3-d6c5-4818-8c54-0caeaabc27a2\r\nserviceRequestId:
>   a239cf9e-006d-8000-7958-e2bb9c6cc4ed" }

Can any one help me in understanding the error message?

**Edit:**

When I try to use JSON displayed in MS Flow in order to update item using REST API, then it worked successfully with the same data.

[image]

And flow throwing

> BAD REQUEST ERROR

Comment: maybe the list item has columns that Flow does not support? What data types are in the list? Maybe you are sending an invalid value to a column? Can you use Flow to update other list items in other lists in other sites?

Comment: Yes. I am able to use it. Every column is Single line of Text, but may be I need to recheck the values. Thanks for focusing. Let me check and get back on this.